How to view and use a previous version of an AWS CloudFormation module?
AWS CloudFormation has a feature for creating a reusable module which is stored in the CloudFormation registry. In the registry, one can view the default version as well as the schema of that version for a given module.
The default version can be set using the cfn CLI via a command like this:
cfn submit --set-default

My question is, how do I view and use a previous version of a module? I can see that all versions of a module are stored as zip files in S3. So, it is possible to download a previous version, extract it, review it, and run the cfn submit --set-default command to create a new version and set it as the default version. Is there a more convenient way to do this, however? For example via the console to review a previous version and restore it as the default version?

The following AWS CloudFormation CLI commands are available for convenience for reviewing a previous module version and setting it as the default version:

aws cloudformation list-type-versions
aws cloudformation describe-type
aws cloudformation set-default-version

